# RVM creates an empty gem set after deletion

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have several rvm gemsets and am trying to delete one of them.

When I run `rvm gemset delete mygemset` it seems to delete the gemset. But then a few minutes later `mygemset` is back, it's now empty but still there.

Any ideas why this gemset won't stay deleted?

I'm running `rvm 1.26.9` on Mac OS 10.9.5

Comment: A few minutes later?  You sure you don't have applications with `.rvmrc` files or something running in the background/terminal windows/etc?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't take very long... maybe a minute before the gemset is back... I don't think there should be anything creating it again. How would I tell?

Comment: How was it created in the first place?  What project uses it?  It's extremely unlikely RVM is just doing that on it's own.

Comment: I created it. I just looked to see if any of my projects still use it, and found one that did. I edited the `.ruby-gemset` file to remove the reference... I'll let you know if it comes back. Thank for looking into this!

Comment: That was it! Removing the references to `mygemset` in `.ruby-gemset` stopped the automatic re-creation of the gemset. Thanks a bunch!